# Printservers compatible with Ubuntu

Tags: hardware, hp

I have an HP LaserJet 1220 printer, and I am looking for a standalone wireless printserver that is compatible with Ubuntu. Many of the wireless printservers available from Linksys require Windows-only drivers to be installed on computers that will use the printserver. What are some printservers that are compatible with Ubuntu, and how much do they cost?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most (if not all) of the HP printers work using HPLIP without installing anything else.
They also can be shared without any additional software (at least to linux machines). You can use CUPS too or samba to share for windows machines.

PS: all software needed have 0 cost

### UPDATE:

In Ubuntu you don't need additional drivers for the print server or router sharing a printer or to connect directly to a wifi printer only the printer driver (that is already included in HPLIP in Ubuntu). You can add a printer and connect to it with ipp.

Have a look at:

[ubuntu forum](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1163728)

[e-how](http://www.ehow.com/how_5396340_set-vista-vista-windows-linux.html)

Comment: I don't think that you understood my question. I am looking for a standalone printserver that I can connect my printer to. Many of the ones I've found require Windows-only drivers.

Comment: Let me see if I can clarify what I understood: They REQUIRE or SUPPLY Windows-only-drivers? The driver is to connect to the printer attached to the print server, right? If so, I don't think Ubuntu will need additional drivers to connect because HPLIP (in Ubuntu) connects very well without anything else to printers connected to and shared by any wifi router (DLink, Linksys, Netgear and others) or even a wifi enabled HP printer (without the router) which seems be the same situation as a hardware print server or I am wrong on this point? For this reason I think any print server will do the job.

Comment: The printservers require and supply windows only drivers for the computers using them.

Comment: updated my answer

Comment: Thank you for the links to look at! Your answer was really helpful!